# How to insert datetime into database with desired timezone?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, pdo

I want to try insert the datetime that set automatically when button clicked. I don't mind about any of that button. I just want to know how the format looks like. i saw about this syntax `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur');` However im using PDO php and want to insert it into database with correct timezone and able to call the time again later with the correct format. I am new to this syntax. So far i just put it before my query and i try to echo it. It did change but when insert, it not change at all. Of course it was before i post this code. Please help. Where should i put it?

```
//=====================
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur');
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s T', time());             

$query = " INSERT INTO record ( 
                bdatetime,
                bstatus,
                bmatricno_fk,
                serialno_fk
           ) VALUES (
                NOW(),
                'NEW',
                :bmatricno,
                :ses
           )"; 

foreach($ses as $s) {                   
    $query_params = array( 
        ':bmatricno' => $_POST['bmatricno'], 
        ':ses' => $s
    );

    try { 
        // Execute the query to create the user 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    } catch(PDOException $ex) { 
        // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
        // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.  
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    }
```

Comment: `date_default_timezone_set` only affects the PHP time zone setting, not the database connection. Either insert the value of `date('Y-m-d H:i:s T', time())` directly in the database or set the database timezone to match what you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur');
$newDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s T', time());


$query = " 
        INSERT INTO record ( 
            bdatetime,
            bstatus,
            bmatricno_fk,
            serialno_fk
        ) VALUES (
            :newDate,
            'NEW',
            :bmatricno,
            :ses
        )
    ";

foreach ($ses as $s) {

    $query_params = array(
        ':bmatricno' => $_POST['bmatricno'],
        ':ses' => $s,
        ':newDate' => $newDate
    );

    try
    {
        // Execute the query to create the user 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    } catch (PDOException $ex)
    {
        // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
        // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.  
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
    }
}
```

You can try this. You should probably read a bit more about PDO.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

And in your case

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php